# Retrieving long values from MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a bunch of fields stored in MongoDB as Longs.  When I query my collection, they are returned as Longs.  However, when I perform a MapReduce into a new collection and retrieve the data from there, it comes back as floats.  It seems awkward to have to cast everything to a float and then grab the Long value - is there a better way?

```
A sample object:
{ "_id" : 2836.0 , "value" : { "friends_count" : 788.0 , "followers_count" : 910.0 , "tweet_count" : 7791.0 , "screen_name" : "zzzzz" , "collected_at" : { "$date" : "2014-01-01T14:47:41.000Z"}}}
```

Here are my map and reduce functions:  I need both the id and all of the numeric values (other than date) to be Longs:

```
String map = "function() { " +
            "emit( this.user_id, { 'friends_count': this.friends_count, 'followers_count': this.followers_count, " +
            "'tweet_count': this.tweet_count, 'screen_name': this.screen_name, 'collected_at': this.collected_at} );}";

String reduce = "function(key, values) { " +
             "var retval = values[0]; " +
             "var latest = 0; "+
             "for(var i in values){ " +
                "if(values[i].collected_at > latest) { " +
                    "latest = values[i].collected_at; "+
                    "retval = values[i]; "+
            "   }} "+
            "return retval;}";
```

Comment: You probably want to declare your accumlator variable in your reduce as NumberLong (assuming you're using the built-in mapreduce)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  Edited the original question to include my map and reduce functions.

Comment: Have some sample input documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this if you change the emitter to emit longs, by using something like:

```
emit(this.user_id, { friends_count: NumberLong(this.friends_count), /* ... */ });
```

It's weird the MongoDB won't keep the existing type, though. Make sure the type of the fields on the original objects is indeed `long` (the object you supplied has floats in it, I assume that's a sample output object and not an input).

Comment: Yes, the original objects were longs, not floats.  Occasionally Mongo would give me a NumberLong, but only occasionally.